# Groovy GStrings and numberformat

Tags: groovy

I'm writing a script in groovy to process some files and I have the following method to create the resulting filename

```
static String formatFileName(String prefix, int counter, String extension) {
    String counterS = String.format('%04d', counter)
    return "$prefix-$counterS$extension"
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of formatting the counter in a GString?

Comment: Not that I know of (unless you consider `"$prefix-${String.format('%04d', counter)}$extension"` more elegant

Comment: or if `"$prefix-${counter.toString().padLeft(4,'0')}$extension"` looks elegant. ;) @tim_yates

Comment: I thought about that but was not convinced, thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frankly, there's not much you can do here. Making this any shorter is basically nitpicking.

As mentioned in [tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509/tim-yates)' comment, you could make this a one-liner

```
return "$prefix-${String.format('%04d', counter)}$extension"
```

I can think of only one way to make it even shorter, which is to give up on GStrings and use `sprintf` instead, which is another example of Groovy goodness. Namely, an [extension method of the `Object` class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html). Personally, I find this easier to read than the braces mashup.

```
return sprintf("%s-%04d%s", prefix, counter, extension)
```